# Caffe CNN: multiple hierarchical losses for hierarchical classification

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

I am familiar with how to use multiple loss in a CNN while all the labels of these loss are identical.

My case here is handling hierarchical labels using multiple losses, as shown in figure bellow:

[image]

loss1 is responsible for labelset1:{Sport, Food}. loss2 for labelset2:{volley, soccer}, loss3 for labelset3:{Pizza, Pasta, burger}. For example, Sample A∈{sport, soccer}, sample B∈{food,burger}.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "don't care" lables, you should have **three** labels for each sample. For example: `{sports, volleyball, don't care}`.
Then you can have the three losses of type `"SoftmaxWithLoss"`. For the two specific losses you should add `ignore_label` for the don't care labels.

Comment: Thanks @Shai. Can you clarify more. So loss1 deals with Label1:{sport, food}. Loss2=> label2:{Pizza, pasta, burger, dont care}, and Loss3 => label3:{volly, soccer, dont care}?

if yes, in this case, different losses are dealing with different labels. how is going to be optimization and general loos? (sum of three?)

Comment: @Nima yes. when loss2 or loss3 have "ignore_label" the loss is zero and so is the gradient wrt that loss term.

Comment: one more thing. How to tell to the CNN when there is dont care in loss2, dont care in loss3 can not happen?

Comment: @Nima the won't know that. You must prepare the labels so. The net does not predict "don't care", it's just the loss that ignores whatever the net predicts when the **ground truth** is "don't care"

Comment: I was confused. I thought "dont care" is an output (label) for the network. So the final outputs are still {pizza, pasta, burger, volley, soccer} and "dont care" is just an ignore flag for training. I got it