# caffe CNN: ignoring multiple labels in loss layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I need to ignore more than 1 label in my loss. I have the following for ignoring labels 1 and 2:

```
layer {
  name: "loss1"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc_19"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss1"
  loss_param {
    ignore_label: 1,2
  }
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 447:21: Expected identifier.
F0730 13:25:41.723671 17862 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/UniMiB-SHAR/resnet/residual-20_train.prototxt
```

any idea how to ignore more than 1 label. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way `ignore_label` is defined in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L451) is

> ```
> // If specified, ignore instances with the given label.
> optional int32 ignore_label = 1;
> ```

The prefix `optional` suggests that caffe proto only supports a **single** ignore label (otherwise a `repeated` prefix would have been used).

If you wish to change that, you would have to change the code of your loss layer as well to ignore all "ignore labels".

BTW, if this question stems from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51574159/1714410), you do not need to have multiple "ignore labels".